# Edit button for deleting rows in UITableView in Swift is not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a table with a custom cell class and a navigation controller. I added an Edit button to the navigation controller and created an IBAction to the View Controller:

```
@IBAction func doEdit(sender: AnyObject) {  
    self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
}
```

Xcode tells me:

```
Cannot invoke 'setEditing' with an argument list of type '(Bool, animated: Bool)'
```

I also tried `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()` in the viewDidLoad method, but the delete icon is not shown there.

**Edit:** I had created an outlet for the UITableView with the name `table`. When typing `self.table.setEditing(true, animated: true)` the above error doesn't show up anymore, but the app crashes, when clicking on the edit button. Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

var arr = ["1", "2", "3"]

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: CustomCellClass = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCellClass   
    cell.cellTitle.text = arr[indexPath.row]   
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 242.0/255.0, green: 157.0/255.0, blue: 48.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)     
    return cell   
}

@IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func doEdit(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.table.setEditing(true, animated: true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()       
    // navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()     
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.table.reloadData()
} 
}
```

Comment: is your "`tableView`" connected as an `IBOutlet` to the table view in that view controller?

Comment: Yes, it is called "table". Please see the updated question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your tableView is connected from `Interface Builder` as an `IBOutlet`.

You can do that by ctrl-dragging from IB to your code.

Answer (score 0):

It works now, I've deleted the outlet and created a new one called `tableView`.